# Retag [c++]+[slicing] to [c++]+[object-slicing]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I'm not familiar with [object-slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-slicing) (349), but it seems that [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)+[slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slicing) (48) should be retagged to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)+[object-slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-slicing) (32). There are only 48 questions that should be retagged. Is my assessment correct?

[slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slicing) mostly contains questions about the array/list slicing which is possible in python and matlab. It currently doesn't have a tag wiki. For example: `arr[3:-2]`.

Comment: Maybe [tag:slicing] -> [tag:slice-indexing] ?

Comment: C happily does array slicing too: Choose the window and pass the start-pointer and element-count. (C++ inherits that). C++ generalizes that with iterators, and ranges while not part of the standard are in boost, and slated for the next standard.

Comment: @Deduplicator I wasn't aware of that, but do you see questions in [`[c++]+[slicing]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slicing%20c%2b%2b) with this kind of slicing? I have only found [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513590/how-to-manage-string-slices-with-less-overhead).

Comment: C++ even has `std::splice`, but Artjom is right: there's only one array slicing question in those 48.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have retagged most of the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)+[slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slicing) (44/49) questions to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)+[object-slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-slicing), but there are some left which I cannot retag without changing the title (they contain a bad bad word).

Thanks to OmnipotentEntity the questions have a non-problematic and sensible title:

[What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)
[Unhandled Exception due to Class slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863183/c-class-slicing-problem-help)
[References and Object Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822146/references-and-the-slicing-problem)

I also proposed an excerpt for slicing:

> Some languages such as pythong or matlab provide an easy way of creating sub-arrays/sub-lists by using a slicing syntax. Example of python is `newlist = somelist[3:7]`. Please use [object-slicing] for the slicing problem in C++ and [program-slicing] for the analysis technique.

Comment: I have fixed the questions with the problematic titles.